# Jupyter notebook does not connect to kernel(2) + Windows 10 Enterprise + ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' --formatted

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda, and created a second environment (i.e. vamp_env) to run my script in Python 3.6.

I build my script a couple of years ago using Python 3.6, and older versions of the packages listed below. I used my script on numerous occasions, it runs well however only with the package versions listed below.

When launching jupyter notebook kernel(1) connects normally, however kernel(2) (vamp_env) does not.

Can someone please help??

My default browser is Google Chrome

Default path: C:\Users\MyName

I followed these steps in Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda create --name vamp_env
conda activate vamp_env
conda install python=3.6
conda install numpy==1.13.3
conda install scipy==0.19.1
conda install pandas==0.20.3
conda install xlrd matplotlib jinja2
conda install -c anaconda ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=vamp_env
```

Then I added the following paths to my environment variables:

```
C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3
C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\bin
```

The following messages appear on Anaconda Prompt:

```
[I 12:49:35.090 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\runpy.py", line 195, in _run_module_as_main "main", mod_spec) 
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in from ipykernel import kernelapp as app    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_init_.py", line 2, in from .connect import *    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in import jupyter_client    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client_init_.py", line 4, in from .connect import *    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 21, in import zmq    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\zmq_init_.py", line 55, in from zmq import backend    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_init_.py", line 40, in reraise(*exc_info)    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise raise value    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend_init_.py", line 27, in _ns = select_backend(first)    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend mod = import(name, fromlist=public_api)    
File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\envs\vamp_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython_init_.py", line 6, in from . import (constants, error, message, context,    
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants'
[W 12:49:38.122 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed    
[W 12:49:38.123 NotebookApp] Kernel 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a died, removing from map.    
[W 12:49:59.815 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from f2b6c540-69d3-46e5-857c-66b244a2e7d9    
[E 12:49:59.817 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: f2b6c540-69d3-46e5-857c-66b244a2e7d9)    
[W 12:50:01.018 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a:1e0dfb64a2384c8e915c30bbf6b9ec23    
[W 12:50:23.362 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a    
[E 12:50:23.363 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a)    
[W 12:50:23.370 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a/channels?session_id=1e0dfb64a2384c8e915c30bbf6b9ec23 (::1): Kernel does not exist: 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a    
[W 12:50:23.391 NotebookApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a/channels?session_id=1e0dfb64a2384c8e915c30bbf6b9ec23 (::1) 22376.820000ms referer=None    
[W 12:50:25.405 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a:1e0dfb64a2384c8e915c30bbf6b9ec23    
[W 12:50:25.710 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 248bb278-4e77-42df-8399-25f7e2b0db9a:1e0dfb64a2384c8e915c30bbf6b9ec23    
[I 12:50:59.521 NotebookApp] Saving file at /test case/STEP_1_3.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Reinstalling Anaconda v5.2 does the trick!